# Why is OpenShift OC "unable to retrieve release image info" when trying to mirror the OKD installation images?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, docker-registry, okd, quay.io

I have been working on getting ready for an installation of OKD on an air-gapped infrastructure. I have been following along with the [procedures on OpenShift's documentation](https://docs.okd.io/latest/installing/install_config/installing-restricted-networks-preparations.html#installing-restricted-networks-preparations) as well as [this supplementary article](https://zhimin-wen.medium.com/airgap-disconnected-installation-of-openshift-4-2-abd7794fc7fe) (because I find the OpenShift documentation to be extremely unclear at certain points).

I have gotten to the point where I have set up my registry with certifications and a pull secret and I am attempting to mirror the images to the registry (which I will later transfer to the air-gapped environment).

The issue that I am having is that when I try to execute the command to mirror the images:

```sh
    oc adm -a ${LOCAL_SECRET_JSON} release mirror \
     --from=quay.io/${PRODUCT_REPO}/${RELEASE_NAME}:${OCP_RELEASE}-${ARCHITECTURE} \
     --to=${LOCAL_REGISTRY}/${LOCAL_REPOSITORY} \
     --to-release-image=${LOCAL_REGISTRY}/${LOCAL_REPOSITORY}:${OCP_RELEASE}-${ARCHITECTURE} --dry-run
```

I get the following error message:

`error: unable to retrieve release image info: unable to load --registry-config: error occurred while trying to unmarshal json`

I have tried searching for this error message in multiple ways, but I just can not find any reference to any specific part of the error message that helps me narrow down the issue.

I have tried to execute the command with and without the `${ARCHITECTURE}` specified, as the OpenShift documentation specifies it and the alternate resource does not. Can anyone point me in the right direction as far as what might be causing this issue?

I am on a VM running Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with my pull_secret.json file. I had used the example from my alternate resource which had several auths with fields populated with ellipses. I thought this was normal. Once I changed the pull_secret to only include my mirror registry domain name, the process continued, albeit with a new error

`unauthorized: access to the requested resource is not authorized`

For the solution to my new error, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64668407/why-am-i-getting-this-unauthorized-error-when-trying-to-mirror-okd-installatio). In a nutshell, the documentation was instructing the user to pull from the wrong repository.